# Trait has same static method as my class - how to resolve?

Tags: php

In my class I am using a trait called `PlankMediable` that has a method `public static function bootMediable()`.

Unfortunately, my class also has a method called `protected static function bootMediable()`.

1. How do I alias the class as once is public static and the other is protected static? Will this work?

```
use PlankMediable  {
    PlankMediable::bootMediable as PlankMediable_bootMediable;
}
```

2. How do I call the static method from my classes `protected static function bootMediable()` class?

Comment: For question 1, have you tried it? What happened? For question 2, remember that a trait is "compiler assisted copy and paste", once imported the methods are part of your class, and can be called like any other method. So again, try it, and let us know if you get any errors you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define an alias with use. Take a look at the following example:

```
trait SayWorld {
    public static function sayHello() {
        echo __METHOD__." from trait";
    }
}

class MyHelloWorld {
    use SayWorld{
     SayWorld::sayHello as traithello;
    }

    public static function sayHello() {
        echo __METHOD__." from class";
    }

    public static function callFromTrait() {
        self::traithello();
    }
}

    MyHelloWorld::traithello();  //SayWorld::sayHello from trait
    MyHelloWorld::sayhello();  //MyHelloWorld::sayHello from class
    MyHelloWorld::callFromTrait();  //SayWorld::sayHello from trait
```